# How to get text from a specific cell in a PDF file in Powershell

Tags: powershell

So I have a program that is supposed to open a PDF in word, get the text from a specific cell, and export it into an excel sheet.

```
Set-StrictMode -Version latest
$file = "C:\PathToPDF.pdf"
$output   = "C:\PathToCSV.csv"
$application = New-Object -comobject word.application
$application.visible = $False

$results = @{}



Function GetWordTable
{
$document = $application.documents.open($file,$false,$true)

$objTable = $document.Tables.Item(1) 


$properties = @{

      Data = $objTable.Cell(5, 5).Range.Text

}
             $results = New-Object -TypeName PsCustomObject -Property $properties
             $results | Export-Csv $output -NoTypeInformation



    $document.close()
    $application.quit()
}

GetWordTable
```

I keep getting an error at the line that populates properties, even though I successfully tested it in a function that seeks out string matches in a word file and exports to excel.

What should I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that the PDF I was using, I thought it was one continuous table but apparently there technically are several distinct tables within it. Thus the code does actually work so long as a valid cell is selected.